# Java,Swing - cannot draw lines on a JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to draw vertical lines to separate days in a week on a JFrame. The code seems fine as no error but when I run it, it output a frame like the picture below. Am I missing anything?

```
public class WeekToView extends JFrame{
    public WeekToView(){

    setTitle("Sheffield Dental Care"); //set title
    Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

    Dimension screenDimensions = toolkit.getScreenSize();
    setLocation(new Point(screenDimensions.width*1/4, screenDimensions.height*1/4)); //set location based on screen size

    JPanel container = new JPanel();
    JScrollPane scrPane = new JScrollPane(container);
    getContentPane().add(scrPane);
    double size[][] = {{150, 150, 150, 150, 150}, // Columns
            {100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100}}; // Rows
    container.setLayout(new TableLayout(size));

    String daysInWeek[] = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"};
    JLabel daysInWeekLabels[] = new JLabel[daysInWeek.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < daysInWeek.length; i++) {
        daysInWeekLabels[i] = new JLabel(daysInWeek[i],SwingConstants.CENTER);
    }

    container.add(daysInWeekLabels[0], "0,0");
    container.add(daysInWeekLabels[1], "1,0");
    container.add(daysInWeekLabels[2], "2,0");
    container.add(daysInWeekLabels[3], "3,0");
    container.add(daysInWeekLabels[4], "4,0");

    setSize(780,600); //set size based on screen size
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false); //unresizable
    setVisible(true);
    }

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g2.drawLine(getWidth()/5,0,getWidth()/5,getHeight());
        g2.drawLine(getWidth()*2/5,0,getWidth()*2/5,getHeight());
        g2.drawLine(getWidth()*3/5,0,getWidth()*3/5,getHeight());
        g2.drawLine(getWidth()*4/5,0,getWidth()*5/5,getHeight());
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: `container.setLayout(new TableLayout(size));` For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Change `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {` to `@Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {` for the start of an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `paintComponent()` method in a JFrame. Whenever you attempt to override a method you should always use `@Override` before the method name. You will get a compile error if you don't override the method correctly.

You could override `paint()` but in general don't try to do custom painting in the `paint()` method of a `JFrame`.

Instead custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent()` method of the panel that you add to the frame.

Better yet you can use a `JTable`, which already provides you with a row/column based component.